# using Hash of hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm still learning Ruby and I have a question concerning hash of hashes. The hash bellow is what I would like to access :

```
reserved_instance_price = [
                              'us-east-1' => ['t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.08, 'm1.medium' => 0.160 ],
                              'us-west-1' => ['t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.08, 'm1.medium' => 0.160 ],
                              'eu-west-1' => ['t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.085, 'm1.medium' => 0.170 ]
                            ]
```

My questions: Is it the right way to implement hashes of hashes in ruby ?  and how to access a particular value ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` syntax is for arrays. To construct hashes use `{}`

Your example becomes

```
reserved_instance_price = {
                              'us-east-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.08, 'm1.medium' => 0.160 }
}
```

For accessing a particular value simply do

`reserved_instance_price['us-east-1']['t1.micro']` which will return `0.02`

If you would like your indexes to be symbols rather than string, you can also use the syntax

```
h = { useast1: {t1micro: 0.02}}
```

Access becomes

```
h[:useast1][:t1micro]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, 'us-east-1' and 't1.micro' are stored in variables, but when I try reserved_instance_price[availability_zone][instance_type]
I get the error:  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: Assuming reserved_instance_price exists, that is probably because ```reserved_instance_price[availability_zone]``` returns ```nil``` (i.e. there is no key in ```reserved_instance_price``` that matches the value of ```availability_zone```)

Comment: It would make since that if you where defining reserved_instance_price as above that your access will indeed return nil. You where declaring it as an array and in ruby, OOB access to arrays always returns nil.